# Затирается символ

Tags: c++

Проблема в том, что когда ввожу число `А = 12`, `B = 2`, то в результате затирается `3` символ (результат : `00_0` , а должно быть `0024`) вместо нижнего подчеркивания значок, как будто там память не проинициализирована, проверял по индексам, результат должен быть правильным вроде как.
P.S
сначала пользователь вводит два числа в строку , потом из строки эти числа помещаются в массивы А и В соответственно , а потом результат умножения записывается в char'овский массив С(естественно с переводом чисел в цифры перед умножением , а после умножения обратно в символы)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void Multiplication(char A[], char B[], char C[], int& size_A, int& size_B,int & max)
{
    int Sdvig=0;
    cout << "size_B" << size_B << endl;
    cout << "size_A" << size_A << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < size_B; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size_A; i++)
        {
            C[Sdvig] += (A[i] * B[j]) % 10; 
            C[Sdvig + 1] += (A[i] * B[j]) / 10; 
        }
        Sdvig++;
        cout <<j<<'\t' << Sdvig << endl;

    }
    
}
int main()
{
    string digit_A, digit_B;
    char A[300], B[300], C[300];

    int size_A, size_B;
    
    int max;
    
    cout << "Enter the first number" << endl;
    cin >> digit_A;
    system("cls");
    cout << "Enter the second number" << endl;
    cin >> digit_B;
    system("cls");
    
    size_A = digit_A.size();
    size_B = digit_B.size();
    
    max = size_A + size_B+1;
    for (int i = size_A - 1; i >= 0; i--) A[size_A - i - 1] = digit_A[i];
    for (int i = size_B - 1; i >= 0; i--) B[size_A - i - 1] = digit_B[i];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) C[i] = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size_A; i++) A[i] -= '0';
    for(int i=0;i<size_B;i++)  B[i] -='0';
    
    Multiplication(A, B, C, size_A, size_B,max);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) C[i] += '0';
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Result : ";
    for (int i = max - 1; i >= 0; i--) cout << C[i];

    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я ввел 12 и 2 но в результате получил что-то странное

Comment: А вообще, что эта программа делает?

Comment: ну вообще я хотел реализовать умножение чисел столбиком(длинная арифметика)

Comment: сначала пользователь вводит два числа в строку , потом из строки эти числа помещаются в массивы А и В соответственно , а потом результат умножения записывается в char'овский массив С(естественно с переводом чисел в цифры перед умножением , а после умножения обратно в символы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил несколько ошибок, и доработал алгоритм умножения до верного:

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://tio.run/##tVTBjpswEL3zFVOq7kIJLWml3VVJkHDUYy/tMYpWFLxZR2AibKJuq3x7OrYxCWzSdg/lYA8zfs8z9hvn222YlxlfHw6vGc/LtqAwY7WQDc2qxDn60MP4OnFagRPwrKJim@UUhCxiZ1ezAr60pWTbkuWZZDX38sesgXS5moC2SG8tlMW4vALBftL79PSHTNCGK6iyH77zywH8lONbsWPreYQEWdM8wRyiWMfyupUwm4FrwK6yjaksyovy3Lr0uC4drnuoG/DUhhu9B06WD@0g8PUik5amHWYzYGCGgVmGFG3LMGSxRe6yEjGeQvuL5QYCYCsfR@NJl@rvbfdHlhsd0xnEAyoLRS7F@Aam0XCBzVpF3w@i@/Nl2PwN8JWuKwiY/4Ia/keeZnT2jtq4yhj3rGSMVqFgayaVvoxBOi0YXX6MIpQh6eaFnmOnV5yVZnf7ZisbRHWeeHpxfeaSNiAfKTywRkjgbfWdNu5IioxDktjcjE88CUkrz81L4frxJVJB85oX/8BKLrIavxH@3ObwTjm8bkXXPTZIBkE9YPG9JvACDSCYjhroqBsIYar6IDH9EIY@nn4fYiq8OiaDKr/ERM4wkWUfGjGRnsm51JfqGnVT4vVrHUZ/AZw2MqhUIZzDdXQd/xlBOgQZI/QwejZRcwT1OBkpcKJexJfVE5zsZOV05kn8SgVmAJ/APVOGuuznp26xC33GGtVQ2TZcneDeORxu76YfbuDm7vY3)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void Multiplication(char A[], char B[], char C[], int& size_A, int& size_B,int & max)
{
    int Sdvig=0, carry = 0;
    cout << "size_B" << size_B << endl;
    cout << "size_A" << size_A << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < size_B; j++)
    {
        carry = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size_A; i++)
        {
            int val = ((int)C[j + i]) + ((int)A[i]) * ((int)B[j]) + carry;
            C[j + i] = val % 10;
            carry = val / 10;
        }
        for (int i = size_A; carry != 0; ++i) {
            int val = ((int)C[j + i]) + carry;
            C[j + i] = val % 10;
            carry = val / 10;
        }
    }
    
}
int main()
{
    string digit_A, digit_B;
    char A[300], B[300], C[300];

    int size_A, size_B;
    
    int max;
    
    cout << "Enter the first number" << endl;
    cin >> digit_A;
    system("cls");
    cout << "Enter the second number" << endl;
    cin >> digit_B;
    system("cls");
    
    size_A = digit_A.size();
    size_B = digit_B.size();
    
    max = size_A + size_B+1;
    for (int i = size_A - 1; i >= 0; i--) A[size_A - i - 1] = digit_A[i];
    for (int i = size_B - 1; i >= 0; i--) B[size_B - i - 1] = digit_B[i];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) C[i] = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size_A; i++) A[i] -= '0';
    for (int i = 0; i < size_B; i++) B[i] -= '0';
    
    Multiplication(A, B, C, size_A, size_B,max);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) C[i] += '0';
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Result : ";
    for (int i = max - 1; i >= 0; i--) cout << C[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Ввод:

```
78126 687
```

Вывод:

```
053672562
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !! А можете пожалуйста обьяснить зачем третий цикл нужен ? просто не совсем понял

Comment: @user436328 Третий это который `for (int i = size_A; carry != 0; ++i) {` ? Он нужен для того чтобы остаточный `carry` перенос прибавить к хвосту. Т.е. после первого цикла `carry` часто будет не нулевой, потому его нужно прибавить к остаточному хвосту числа (старшим разрядам). Почему цикл? Т.к. один раз прибавление к старшему разряду может вызвать ещё раз переполнение как например `9 + 9 = 18` (здесь перенос `1`) и ещё раз и ещё раз, и потому может придётся иногда (редко) много разрядов прибавлять с переносом. Например если старшие разряды `999999` и прибавим перенос `1`  то будет цикл 6 раз.